# Scala Pattern Matching with Tailrec function

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

I have the following function that does a Tailrec and tries to do a character count in a given String:

```
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def letterCount(remaining: Seq[Char], acc: Map[Char, Int]): Map[Char, Int] = remaining match {
    case Nil => acc
    case x :: Nil => acc ++ Map(x -> 1)
    case x :: xs =>
      letterCount(xs.filter(_ == x), acc ++ Map(x -> xs.count(_ == x)))
  }

  letterCount("aabbccd".toSeq, Map.empty)
```

For some strange reason, it fails with a match error:

```
scala.MatchError: aabbccd (of class scala.collection.immutable.WrappedString)
    at $line87.$read$$iw$$iw$.letterCount(<pastie>:14)
    at $line87.$read$$iw$$iw$.liftedTree1$1(<pastie>:23)
    at $line87.$read$$iw$$iw$.<init>(<pastie>:22)
    at $line87.$read$$iw$$iw$.<clinit>(<pastie>)
    at $line87.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<pastie>:7)
    at $line87.$eval$.$print(<pastie>:6)
    at $line87.$eval.$print(<pastie>)
```

I could not find out what the problem could be! Any ideas?

Comment: A `Seq` is not a `List`, `letterCount("aabbccd".toList, Map.empty)` works (in the sense that it doesn't throw), but it has some logic issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `Seq` is not a `List`. `Seq` has no `Nil` element and has no `::` method.

If you want to keep with `Seq[Char]` you could do this.

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec
def letterCount(remaining: Seq[Char], acc: Map[Char, Int]): Map[Char, Int] = remaining match {
  case Seq() => acc
  case x +: xs =>
    letterCount(xs.filter(_ != x), acc ++ Map(x -> (xs.count(_ == x)+1)))
}

letterCount("aabbccd", Map.empty)
```

Notice that you don't have to `.toSeq` the `String`. It is automatically interpreted as a `Seq[Char]`.

Answer (score 1):

Here it works:

```
  @scala.annotation.tailrec
  def letterCount(original: List[Char], remaining: List[Char], acc: Map[Char, Int]): Map[Char, Int] = remaining match {
    case Nil => acc
    case x :: Nil => acc ++ Map(x -> 1)
    case x :: xs =>
      letterCount(original, xs.filter(_ != x), acc ++ Map(x -> original.count(_ == x)))
  }
  letterCount("aabbccd".toList, "aabbccd".toList, Map.empty)
```

Alternatively, a foldLeft also works like this:

```
"aabbccd".foldLeft[Map[Char,Int]](Map.empty)((map, c) => map + (c -> (map.getOrElse(c, 0) + 1)))
```